# How get fields of object in parameter iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm passing the object "OrdemServico" as parameter to report.

```
OrdemServico ordemServico = new OrdemServico();  
ordemServico.setCodigo("CA123");
mapa.put("ORDEMSERVICO", ordemServico);
```

And on the .jrxml i added a parameter with same name of the parameter in map. how i can get the fields of the object? Tnks

Comment: `how i can get the fields of the object?` - Example: `$P{ORDEMSERVICO}.getCodigo()` or `((OrdemServico) $P{ORDEMSERVICO}).getCodigo()`. You need also add import and declare the parameter

Comment: Working with casting :)) Tnks @AlexK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You need also add import and declare the parameter

Great.

To work here:

```
<parameter name="RelatorioMaquina" class="br.pro.x87.reports.RelatorioMaquina"/>
```

and to acess the field:

```
$P{RelatorioMaquina}.getDescricao()
```